# Connect MariaDB through Spring and Hibernate using SSL (Self-Signed) certificates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0, mariadb

I have developed the J2EE application with Spring and Hibernate. Now I wanted to connect my application with MariaDB with SSL certificate (without using password)
I can able to connect to my database by using following command

```
mysql -h myhost.com -P3306 -umyuser --ssl-ca ca.crt --ssl-cert app.crt --ssl-key my-key.pem
```

but I can not able to connect My Application with the database as I am getting following error

***Error Log***

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 71 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor37.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1322)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2198)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:89)
    ... 21 more
```

After reading this ***[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)*** I have added the certificate into keystore with the following command:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "My App Certificate" -file ca.crt -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass mypassword
```

still getting following error following is my configuration files

**JDBC.properties**

```
jdbc.initialPoolSize=10
jdbc.maxPoolSize=30
jdbc.minPoolSize=5
jdbc.acquireIncrement=3
jdbc.acquireRetryAttempts=0
jdbc.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1
jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod=600
jdbc.numHelperThreads=10
jdbc.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true
jdbc.mydbUrl=jdbc:mysql://myhost.com:3306/mydb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&characterEncoding=utf8
jdbc.mydbUsername=myuser
```

**datasource-context.xml**

```
<bean id="mydbCommon" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" abstract="true" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.rptdbDriverClassName}"/>
    <!-- Common properties for all DS -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${jdbc.initialPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${jdbc.acquireRetryAttempts}"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${jdbc.preferredTestQuery}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod}"/>
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${jdbc.numHelperThreads}"/>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${jdbc.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mydb" parent="mydbCommon">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.mydbUrl}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.mydbUsername}"/>
</bean>
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the steps that I have follow to solve my problem this is not my creativity just gather some steps mentioned in following articles.

**References**

***[Connecting Securely Using SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)***

***[The Most Common OpenSSL Commands](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)***

In order to make use of SSL encryption to connect to your database, you will need:

- The assistance of your database administrator to configure the MySQL
  server to accept SSL connections.
- The SSL PEM public-key file that corresponds to your server's
  encryption key.

**Steps to check your MySQL server has SSL support**

Use following command to check your server has support for SSL or not

```
show variables like 'have_ssl'
```

If the answer from your server is

**NO** then the server has no SSL support compiled into it.
**DISABLED**, your system administrator does not start the MySQL server with SSL enabled.
**YES**, you may be able to use SSL.

IF you want ot Configuring MySQL for SSL then you following MySql documentation

*[6.3.6.2 Configuring MySQL for SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)*

**Follow below steps to configure your Java environment to use the server's SSL certificate with JDBC.**

The system works through two Java truststore files,

- One file contains the certificate information for the server
  (truststore in the examples below)
- The other file contains the certificate for the client (keystore in
  the examples below)

*NOTE: All Java truststore files are password protected by supplying a suitable password to the keytool when you create the files. 
You need the file names and associated passwords to create an SSL connection.*

**Create truststore File.**

You will first need to import the MySQL server CA Certificate into a Java truststore. 
A sample MySQL server CA Certificate is located in the SSL subdirectory of the MySQL source distribution. This is what SSL will use to determine if you are communicating with a secure MySQL server. Alternatively, use the CA Certificate that you have generated or been provided with by your SSL provider.

*NOTE: Assuming that keytool is in your path. The keytool is typically located in the bin subdirectory of your JDK or JRE*

```
shell> keytool -import -alias dbServerCACert -file ca.crt -keystore truststore
    Enter keystore password: truststorepwd 
    Re-enter new password: truststorepwd
    ....    
    Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
    Certificate was added to keystore
```

**Create Keystore File.**

Firts we have to generate an empty Java keystore file using following command

```
shell>keytool -genkey -alias dbkeystore -keystore my-app.jks
    Enter keystore password:  
    Re-enter new password: 
    What is your first and last name?
      [Unknown]:  mycomp
    What is the name of your organizational unit?
      [Unknown]:  mycomp
    What is the name of your organization?
      [Unknown]:  mycomp
    What is the name of your City or Locality?
      [Unknown]:  Singapore
    What is the name of your State or Province?
      [Unknown]:  Singapore
    What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
      [Unknown]:  SG
    Is CN=mycomp , OU=mycomp, O=mycomp, L=Singapore, ST=Singapore, C=SG correct?
      [no]:  yes

    Enter key password for <keystore>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):

    shell>keytool -delete -alias dbkeystore -keystore my-app.jks
    Enter keystore password: keystorepwd
```

Convert your client certificate (my-app.crt) and Private Key(my-app.key) to pkcs12 file using following command

```
shell>openssl pkcs12 -export -name dbkeystore -in my-app.crt -inkey my-app.key -out my-app.p12
    Enter Export Password: keystorepwd 
    Verifying - Enter Export Password: keystorepwd
```

Import your p12 file into keystore using following command

```
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore my-db.jks -srckeystore my-app.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias dbkeystore
```

**SET JVM Veriables**

Finally, to use the keystore and truststore that you have generated, you need to set the following system properties of JVM

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/my-app.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystorepwd
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststorepwd
```

**Update your Connection URL to support SSL**

You will also need to set useSSL to true in your connection parameters for MySQL Connector/J, either by adding useSSL=true to your URL

```
jdbc:mysql://<HOST>:<PORT>/DB?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

**Run Test Application to check everything is working file**

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://<HOST>:<PORT>/DB?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true"
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            // STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this steps work for me hope this will help you....!